# Automated MySQL community server installation

Tags: mysql, installation, server

Is it possible to create an automated installation for MySQL community server 8, for example by providing a text file with the desired settings?

I found this is possible for MySQL Enterprise but could not find a reference for the community server.
The only parameters I want to change is the port number and add a user + password (and i guess I have to provide a root password too).

Comment: When (trying) to install software, it's pretty important to know on what kind of Operating system, you want to install this software.

Comment: Windows 10 and 11. Sorry, I forgot to say.

Comment: Did you try `mysql-installer-community-8.0.28.0.msi /i /passive`  or `mysql-installer-community-8.0.28.0.msi /?`  and add some steps (in a batch file) to set root password, and change port number, etc)

Comment: Ah, you are pointing me into the direction Windows Installer features. Yes, I'm going to try this. A combination of /passive and /package might do the job, combined with a batch file to do some fine tuning. I'm going to consult the Windows Installer SDK as this seems to be the primary source of information. I will come back to this question when I have succeeded or have any additional questions.